# Install Wine on elementary OS Juno

Tags: software-installation, wine

I'm trying to install Wine stable.

I used the following code:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

and it say:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 4.0~cosmic) but it is not 
going to be installed
           Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Pls help me

Comment: Please try `sudo apt install wine-stable` and let me what you find.

Answer (score 3):

Must it necessarily be from the terminal?

you can use appcenter and install from there wine.

I would also recommend using playonlinux, so you can even manage the different versions of wine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using some PPA or your ***/etc/apt/sources.list*** is messed up. Elementary OS Juno is based on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic). `cosmic` in the output looks suspicious. Remove the 3rd party PPA and restore your software sources to official sources and retry installation.